# Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function recursion (consistent-return)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

What if I have a recursive function like below? Can I just return false after the recursive `foo` call?

```
function foo(fn, redo, interval = 1000) {
  return new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
      fn()
        .then(resolve)
        .catch((error) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            if (redo === 1) {
              reject(error);
              const unusedComponent = () => null;
              return unusedComponent;
            }

            foo(fn, retriesLeft - 1, interval).then(resolve, reject);
          }, interval);
          return null;
        });
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Is something about this not working? This code looks like it should work already, although it could be cleaned up and shortened significantly. The return value from a function given to `setTimeout` will be discarded so it doesn't matter what you return after the recursive `foo` call, so returning `false` or not returning at all will give the same result.

Comment: it was still erroring with prettier, so i wanted a way around it. I found it by returning the recursive call

Answer (score 0):

Return recursive call by adding in return on the foo